# How to write a iTunes plug-in that provides frequency information

Tags: c, audio, itunes, signal-processing

Looking at a sample code for the iTunes visualizer API, there is a data `struct` that contains waveform and spectrum data:

```
struct RenderVisualData {
    UInt8 numWaveformChannels;
    UInt8 waveformData[kVisualMaxDataChannels][kVisualNumWaveformEntries];

    UInt8 numSpectrumChannels;
    UInt8 spectrumData[kVisualMaxDataChannels][kVisualNumSpectrumEntries];
};
typedef struct RenderVisualData RenderVisualData;
```

There are 2 channels (`kVisualMaxDataChannels`) and 512 waveform and spectrum data points (`kVisualNumWaveformEntries` and `kVisualNumSpectrumEntries`), the equivalent of integers between 0 and 255.

These are useful for visual representations of audio. I would like to convert these data (or similar) to frequencies measured in `Hz`, in order to convert them to musical notation (notes, essentially).

What resources, algorithms etc. are involved with this process? Are these data Fourier coefficients? Given this data, how might I get back to a frequency at a given time point, which I can map to a note?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking some open-source projects and try learning from them. [FFT Guitar Tuner](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/FftGuitarTuner.aspx). Also, if you are more serious learning DSP, you can search you tube for Digital Signal Processing and watch full lecture series on this subject. Finding the musical note of an audio chunk isnt the easiest task, as I am finding out myself trying to program a guitar tuner. As I understand(im not an expert of this field) the steps that need to be taken for acquiring pitch information are:

1. take some samples of audio data, preferably in the power of two(256,512, 1024 etc)
2. (optional) Apply a window function, so that it would smooth out the edges and appear as if continous time signal(end-point matches starting point).
3. Take Fast Fourier Transform
4. Pitch extraction algorithm. There are several different algorithms, depending on your needs. The easiest in my experience is Harmonic Product Spectrum, that will find fundamental frequency of the audio chunk you processed.

Answer (score 1):

Two warnings.  Spectrum data and musical notes are not the same thing.  Spectrum data from an FFT has a completely different spacing in frequency between each frequency bin (or array element) than between equal tempered musical pitches, and a single musical pitch is usually represented by a rich spectrum containing a lot more than 1 spectral frequency bin.

The center frequency of each bin is related to the sample rate divided by the length of the data processed by the implied FFT.